# Avoid view to be refreshed in a tab based app in react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a simple tabbar app.
One of the tabs renders a view where I display pictures fetched remotely.
The issue I'm facing is, whenever I switch tabs, the images are re-displayed, despite the fact than neider render is called again, nor shouldComponentUpdate.
This results in a very bad user experience as the view is refreshed over and over again.

Any idea of how I can fix it?

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

class TabIssue extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'tab1',
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Build an array of 60 photos
    let items = Array.apply(null, Array(60)).map((v, i) => {
      return { id: i, src: 'http://placehold.it/200x200?text='+(i+1) }
    });
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TabBarIOS>
        <TabBarIOS.Item title="Tab #1"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tab1'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({ selectedTab: 'tab1', });
          }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
            <Text> toto</Text>
          </View>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
        <TabBarIOS.Item title="Tab #2"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tab2'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({ selectedTab: 'tab2', });
          }}>
          <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.galleryContainer}>
            {
              this.state.items.map((item) => {
                return(
                  <View key={item.id} style={styles.pictureContainer}>
                    <Image source={{uri: item.src}} style={styles.picture} />
                  </View>
                )
              })
            }
            </View>
          </ScrollView> 
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  galleryContainer: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  picture: {
    height: width/2 - 4,
    width: width/2 -4,
    flex: 1,
  },
  pictureContainer: {
    padding: 2
  }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TabIssue', () => TabIssue);
```

Comment: If i understood your problem you have tab bar and on top of it you have two images. on click of images your view is not refreshing? if possible please attach image of what you want to achieve. if you can provide some amount of code some one can help you.

Comment: Post your code as to what you have tried already.

Comment: I've added a basic example.
To be more clear:
I tap on tab 2, the view shows the pictures
I tap back on tab 1 
then I tap on tab 2, instead of showing up instantly there a few milliseconds of delay. so you can see a blank screen then pictures show up

Comment: Have you tried setting `removeClippedSubviews` to `false` on your `scrollView`? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#removeclippedsubviews Though I think React Native is doing something magic with images in general, I seem to have the same issue, even with local images.

Comment: Yeah I just tried it. And the issue remains I think there might be some setting to do but I have no idea what